# How to Add Thumbnail in Generic Google Wallet Pass

Tags: c#, google-wallet

Is there a way to add Member Photo as thumbnail in Google Wallet Generic Pass. According to the documentation a Logo can be added on top let side, but I want to add image in body. Also if the Logo is the only way then is this possible to change the location or size of that

Thanks

Comment: Please show your existing code for adding an item to Google Wallet.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.